# Getting a picker to always show the first element of my array when user select a text field in Xcode

Tags: xcode, uipickerview

I am building an app that asks the user to select a number that represents scoring from 0 to 6. I give the user the seven options via a picker view. This actions need to be repeated several times until the user has accumulated enough points.

My issue is that, after the initial pick which properly loads on first choice of my array ("0"), the wheel then displays the previous choice made by the user ("3" if choice was "3", "4" if it was "4", etc..) instead of "0" again.

There should be a simple method to call the picker to repeatedly display the first element of the array of data but I can't find it. As you can see I am new to this... Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a `UIPickerView` called `picker`.
Just call then (see [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614382-selectrow))

```
picker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true))
```

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If so, please accept the answer so that the question is marked as such. If not, was is wrong or missing?

Comment: Yes it did solve the answer, albeit one small issue. If I implement your code and say change the first parameter to display the third row it will only work on the second time the picker is called upon. The first time it is invoked it still shows row 1 and then afterwards works properly to display row 3.

Comment: If you want to have a certain row selected when the picker is shown the 1st time, you had to call `picker.selectRow` before it is shown, i.e. either in `viewWillAppear` or in `viewDidLoad`.